# How to implement Aspect on Spring crud repository methods

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, aspectj

I'm doing a project in which we have lot of entities on which we will be doing CRUD operations. I have created a base entity class and in all the other entities i have extended the base entity class which is having common fields like created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by etc. Now, i want to implement aspect on Spring CrudRepository methods and set the above mentioned fields while saving.

I've tried implementing something like this but not working.

```
package com.cerium.aop;

import java.util.Date;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.cerium.datamodel.AccountDataModel;
import com.cerium.domain.Account;
import com.cerium.domain.BaseEntity;
import com.cerium.util.Constants;

/**
 * @author Manikanta B Cerium
 *
 */
@Component
@Aspect
public class SampleAspect {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleAspect.class);

    @Around("execution(* com.cerium.repository.*.save (com.cerium.domain.BaseEntity)) && args(saveData)")
    public Object beforeSave(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Object saveData) throws Throwable {

        LOG.debug("Into aspect before save: {}", saveData);

        BaseEntity baseEntity = (BaseEntity) proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(new Object[] { saveData });

        // set the fields here......
        baseEntity.setCreatedDate(new Date());

        System.out.println(saveData);

        return baseEntity;

    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to find out what went wrong for you because I only see an aspect, but not the actual code (package name, class and method declarations) targeted by it. Another question is: Is Spring AOP configured correctly, i.e. does it work at all, e.g. for a simple pointcut like `execution(* *(..))` and a simple `@Before` advice or maybe a simple `@Around` advice which only proceeds and returns the result, nothing else?

Answer (score 3):

To work with aspect we should first define a pointcut method with the filter expression (in your case for 'save' methods), then create a method to handle this pointcut:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class CommonSaveAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.cerium.repository.*.save(..))")
    public void commonSave() {
    }

    @Around("commonSave()")
    public Object addCommonData(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();

        if (Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(args[0].getClass())) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            Iterable<BaseEntity> entities = (Iterable<BaseEntity>) args[0];
            entities.forEach(entity -> {
                // set the fields here...
            });
        }

        if (args[0] instanceof BaseEntity) {
            BaseEntity entity = (BaseEntity) args[0];
            // set the fields here...
        }

        return pjp.proceed(args); 
    }
}
```

[More info](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-advice-tutorial)